# How to create an empty csv file in php?

Tags: php, fopen

I have tried creating creating but I do not know how to download. How do I create an empty CSV file that can be viewed on the web page, manipulated and downloaded in php?

```
 <?php
             $new_csv= fopen('/scoresheet.csv' , 'w');
             fputcsv($new_csv, $row);
             fclose($new_csv);

             header("content-type:text/csv");
             header("content-disposition:attachment; filename=scoresheet.csv");
             readfile("/scoresheet.csv");
            ?>
            <a href='excel.php?request=".$id."' class='btn btn-primary'>Download</a>
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with mysql and pdo?  Have you researched StackOverflow and the php manual?  It doesn't look like you are writing an empty csv file.

Comment: You want to 1.Create it 2. View it 3. Manipulate it 4. Download it ==== Too Broad

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 5):

You can generate a file with file_put_contents()

```
file_put_contents('file.csv', $content);
```

and you can output the file on your webpage with file_get_contents()

```
file_get_contents('file.csv');
```

Comment: i dont understand .. im just a novice